# JavaFX 8 WebEngine print method unable to print in Landscape

Tags: printing, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

I'm trying to print a HTML page within a JavaFX WebView (JavaFX 8_25) on A4 paper in Landscape orientation but it prints out with Portrait orientation with a tiny font size

```
printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE, Printer.MarginType.DEFAULT);
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob(printer);
if (job != null) {
    System.out.println(job.getJobSettings().getPageLayout());
    webEngine.print(job);
    job.endJob();
}
```

The System.out shows the portrait orientation

Paper=Paper: A4 (210 x 297mm) size=594.90087890625x841.3598022460938 MM Orient=PORTRAIT leftMargin=54.0 rightMargin=54.0 topMargin=54.0 bottomMargin=54.0

I'm finding the only way I can print the HTML page in Landscape mode is by calling the print job's showPageSetupDialog method just prior to printing.

```
printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE, Printer.MarginType.DEFAULT);
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob(printer);
if (job != null) {
    if(job.showPageSetupDialog(null)) {
        System.out.println(job.getJobSettings().getPageLayout());
        webEngine.print(job);
        job.endJob();
    }
}
```

If I select Landscape in the Page Setup dialog, the System.out shows

Paper=Paper: A4 size=210.0x297.0 MM Orient=LANDSCAPE leftMargin=54.0 rightMargin=53.11810302734375 topMargin=51.995269775390625 bottomMargin=54.0

I have a problem with the dialog in that I have to set A4 and Landscape every time.

I have 3 questions: -

1. Why is the webEngine.print not using the PageLayout I have passed in to the printer?
2. Is it possible to get Landscape orientation on a webEngine.print(job); without having to set it via the Page Setup Dialog?
3. If I have to use the Page Setup Dialog, is there any way JavaFX can remember what I set for the page setup for the next print job i.e. A4 and Landscape?

While typing this I have also tried

```
print{@page {size: landscape}}
```

within a style tag on HTML page but that didn't work either.

Thanks

Comment: how is the print quality when you do this?

Comment: I'm finding the print quality is good.  I didn't notice the print was degraded in any way when printed from a good laser printer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the `PageLayout` to the `JobSettings` of your `PrinterJob`, using the method `job.getJobSettings().setPageLayout(PageLayout)`

Try this code:

```
PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, 
                                PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE, Printer.MarginType.DEFAULT);
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob(printer);
job.getJobSettings().setPageLayout(pageLayout);
if (job != null) {
    System.out.println(job.getJobSettings().getPageLayout());
    webEngine.print(job);
    job.endJob();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  That works!!  Do you know why the PageLayout has to be set at both the printer and the job?

Comment: `printer.createPageLayout()` creates a `pageLayout`. It doesn't set it.